# Program terminating abnormally if input is very large

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define n ((sizeof(char)) * 100 )

int stringlength(char * str)
{
    int count=0;
    while(*str)
    {  
        if(*str == '\n')
        {
            *str=0;
        }
        else
            count++, str++;
    }
    return count;
}


int palin1(char *str, int k)
{
    char * pend = str + k - 1;
    if(*pend != *str)
        return 0;
    else
        palin1(str+1, k-1);
       return 1;
}    

int palin(char *str)
{
    int length = stringlength(str), f=0;
    char *pend = str + length - 1;
    while(str <= pend)
    {
        if(*str == *pend) f=1;
        else
            return (f = 0);
        str++, pend--;
    }
    return 1;
}

main()
{
    char * ps = (char *)malloc(n);
    int flag;
    if(ps == NULL) printf("Malloc Fail\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Malloc Succeeded, you have memory of %d bytes\n", n);
        printf("This program checks if String is Palindrome or not\n\
        \nEnter your String: ");
        fgets(ps, 100, stdin);
        printf("You entered: %s of length %d", ps, stringlength(ps));
        int i = 0;
        printf("\n\nEnter:\n1.Using iteration\n2.Using Recursion ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                flag=palin(ps);
                break;
            case 2:
                flag=palin1(ps,stringlength(ps));
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid input");
        }

        if(flag) printf("\nYou entered a Palindrome");
        else  printf("\nNot a Palindrome");
    }
    free (ps);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the above program http://www.ideone.com/qpGxi does not give any output on putting the input:

> mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

I know `fgets(ps,100,stdin)` will take only 100 characters and not more than that, but why does the program halt execution?

Comment: This is just awesome :-)) `#define n ((sizeof(char)) * 100 )`

Comment: Haha, yeah that is pretty unnecessary. I've never seen a system where (sizeof(char)) wasn't equal to 1.

Comment: @Lohit: I suggest you do not define lower case identifiers. I've once had to debug a trainee code with such a `#define` which started to fail compilation when he introduced a variable with the same name ... took me a lot of time to find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for `fgets` failure, as recommended by the [fgets spec](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/).

```
if ( fgets(ps,100,stdin) == NULL ) {
    printf("Input failed.");
    //check for 'feof' or 'ferror' here
    return -1;
}
printf("You entered: %s of length %d",ps,stringlength(ps));
```

I don't see why `fgets` would be failing, but you would get an uninitialized character buffer back, which would crash `printf`.

**EDIT:** You should really pay attention to your compiler warnings, too.

```
prog.c:49: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:59: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
prog.c:63: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
prog.c: In function ‘palin’:
prog.c:46: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:52: warning: ‘flag’ may be used uninitialized in this function
```

You can see that even your compiler recommends checking `fgets` for null. Also, `flag` should be set to `0` in the default case, otherwise you will get undefined behavior if the user enters something other than `1` or `2`.

**EDIT 2:** Oh for Christ's sake! your program works fine! You forgot to check **"run program"** in Ideone!!!

http://www.ideone.com/7ecZd

Answer (score 0):

It's terminating because there are characters left in the input stream if the input is too large. For example, if you wish to take only **5** characters using `fgets` but have given the input as -

> StackOverflow

`Overflow` are left in the input stream. They need to be removed from the stream for further input operations to succeed. So, remove those extra characters from the stream using -

```
fgets(ps,100,stdin);
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

Since the input stream is struck with offending characters, the `scanf` statement that actually takes the user input is not working and jumping to subsequent operations.

Also initialize the `flag` variable to **0** other wise it has garbage values.

Comment: Why not just `fflush(stdin)` if the input stream really contains something?

Comment: Because `fflush` is only defined for output or update streams; it doesn't clear out the input stream.

Comment: @JohnBode can you provide something which i can read about fflush, which explicitly states fflush is not defined for input streams? i have been looking but not getting anything.

Comment: @Lohit: From the language standard, 7.19.5.2/2: "If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot break a string literal just like that

```
printf("%s\n", "string literal **WRONGLY**\n
broken right after the line break.");
```

What you can do is use the preprocessor feature of joining successive string literals to make just one

```
printf("%s\n", "string literal **CORRECTLY**\n"
"broken because the preprocessor joins these 2 parts.");
```